# Java8, Is there a filtering collector?

Tags: java, predicates, collectors

I want to group a collection but I don't want the aggregations to include some values. What's the best solution to do that?

A solution could be a collector `filtering(Predicate,Collector)` but there is no such collector. Is there any way to do it without implementing your own collector?

```
IntStream.range(0,100).collect(
    groupingBy(
       i -> i % 3,
       HashMap::new,
       filtering( i -> i % 2 == 0, toSet() )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only other way I'm aware of is to do the filtering beforehand, that is,

```
 stream.filter(filterPredicate).collect(collector)
```

That said, it's not clear what you're actually trying to do with your filtering function, which takes three arguments instead of two.

I suspect you are trying to map a function over elements that match a filter, but that's itself a map, which you can do easily enough:

```
 Collectors.mapping(input -> condition(input) ? function(input) : input, collector)
```

And making your own collector isn't actually that difficult:

```
static <T, A, R> Collector<T, A, R> filtering(
    Predicate<? super T> filter, Collector<T, A, R> collector) {
  return Collector.of(
      collector.supplier(),
      (accumulator, input) -> {
         if (filter.test(input)) {
            collector.accumulator().accept(accumulator, input);
         }
      },
      collector.combiner(),
      collector.finisher());
}
```

Comment: The filtering function should take 2 arguments, corrected. The result is of type `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`. I want the Sets to contain only elements that satisfy predicate `i -> i % 2 == 0`. I can't filter the collection before grouping because then the result will not contain some groups(in general case).

Comment: Then I think you're pretty much down to making your own collector as I described.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 9 there's a new [filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector :

```
Map<Department, Set<Employee>> wellPaidEmployeesByDepartment = employees.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
      filtering(e -> e.getSalary() > 2000, toSet())));
```

Comment: This is better than a plain stream `filter()`, if you want the possibility for an empty group after filtering. Filtering before collecting would simply omit that group.